# Use Jquery UI autocomplete with ID value instead text

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the autocomplete widget to enable the end user to search a person of my application but then I don't want to send the person name to server but the ID of the person. Is there some best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Look at api [doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

The source can be either an array of strings, or

> an array of objects with label and value properties [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

so use this second solution, in your case, something like that :

```
[{label:"PersonName1", value="1"}, {label:"PersonName2", value="2}}
```

In that case, search (and display value) will be the `label`, but input value will be... `value`.